# ScrollTop animate jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying how to animate the scrollTop function in the first script but everytime I do it, the second script that makes the div full height of the page does not work anymore.

So every time

```
 $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: top
            }, function () {
                $prev.addClass('current');
            });
```

this becomes

```
   $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: top
                easing:'easeOutElastic'
            }, function () {
                $prev.addClass('current');
            });
```

The second script stops working.

http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/479/

Comment: You need a comma after `top` and before `easing`. Every key:value pair in an object literal is comma separated

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem: The Jsfiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: I added a css declaration: `.current{background-color:red}` to ensure that the `.current` class was being added correctly. It is happening AFTER the scroll is finish, not sure if that is intentional or not, but is being added. Is the issue that you're trying to edit the easing function?

Comment: The comma does not work. I am trying to make an effect in every transition after the "transition" like this plugin does http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also include jquery-ui.js for easing effects.
Then you can use easing effects in syntax `.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

In your example it would be -

```
 $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: top
  },1000,'easeOutElastic', function () {
     $prev.addClass('current');
  });
```

Comment: Thank you sir! It works! But if I would like to add an effect and not an easing, which would be the correct syntax for adding an effect to the scroll, like a fade effect from jquery-ui.js?

Comment: Since the animate method doesn't take such arguments you can perform any effect in the callback function.